# Can two addresses ever have the same sorting value?

Tags: javascript, addresses, uniswap

From [uniswap](/questions/tagged/uniswap) [documentation](https://uniswap.org/docs/v2/smart-contracts/pair/) it says:

```
token0
function token0() external view returns (address);
Returns the address of the pair token with the lower sort order.

token1
function token1() external view returns (address);
Returns the address of the pair token with the higher sort order.
```

As far as I understand, in order to compare them in [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), I would need to cast them to `BigInt`, i.e.

```
let token0;
let token1;

const address0 = BigInt('0xDB17618B140EFCB8a07BC8e9b88920de1daE6C87');
const address1 = BigInt('0x4d4CC29b9C4E413CFe5f898E16280f11db57E186');

if (address0 < address1) {
  token0 = address0;
  token1 = address1;
} else {
  token0 = address1;
  token1 = address0;
}
```

Two questions:

1. Is there ever a case where two distinct addresses will have the same sorting value?
2. If yes, then should I be using `<=` or `<` here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there ever a case where two distinct addresses will have the same sorting value?

Each address is necessarily unique. Each address is a 20-byte number. Therefore unique numbers.

(If you're worried about the checksum-ing - i.e. the capitalization in various places - that still doesn't affect the underlying value.)

The [Uniswap Factory contract](https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v2-core/blob/master/contracts/UniswapV2Factory.sol#L23) does the comparison in the same way:

```
function createPair(address tokenA, address tokenB) external returns (address pair) {
    require(tokenA != tokenB, 'UniswapV2: IDENTICAL_ADDRESSES');
--> (address token0, address token1) = tokenA < tokenB ? (tokenA, tokenB) : (tokenB, tokenA);
    require(token0 != address(0), 'UniswapV2: ZERO_ADDRESS');
    ...
```